# Rails 3.1rc1 to_param, from_param without effect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

as I am used to I tried something like the following in a recent Rails 3.1rc1 app:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'digest/sha1'

  belongs_to :user
  after_create :set_uuid

  def set_uuid
    self.update_attribute :uuid, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{APP_CONFIG[:salt]}_#{self.class}_#{self.id}")[0..14]
  end

  def self.from_param param
    self.find_by_uuid! param
  end

  def to_param
    self.uuid
  end

end
```

Unforunately this does not seem to have any effect anymore. When I request:

```
http://localhost:3000/foos/3a2c4aa7d42adf3
```

the following SQL is issued:

```
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3a2c4aa7d42adf3"]]
```

To achive my goal I could also simply:

```
set_primary_key 'uuid'
```

I know, but that's not the way I'd like to solve this problem.

Does anyone of you have some advice for me? Thx in advance.

Felix

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your controller is calling `Foo.from_param(params[:id])`? If you're using scaffolding, it's most likely doing the normal `Foo.find(params[:id])`